# Changing iterable variable during loop

Tags: python, for-loop

Let `it` be an iterable element in python.
In what cases is a change of `it` inside a loop over `it` reflected? Or more straightforward: When does something like this work?

```
it = range(6)
for i in it:
    it.remove(i+1)
    print i
```

Leads to 0,2,4 being printed (showing the loop runs 3 times).

On the other hand does

```
it = range(6)
for i in it:
    it = it[:-2]
    print it
```

lead to the output:

```
[0,1,2,3]
[0,1]
[]
[]
[]
[],
```

showing the loop runs 6 times. I guess it has something to do with in-place operations or variable scope but cannot wrap my head around it 100% sure.

**Clearification:**

One example, that doesn't work:

```
it = range(6)
for i in it:
    it = it.remove(i+1)
    print it
```

leads to 'None' being printed and an Error (NoneType has no attribute 'remove') to be thrown.

Comment: In the second example, you're **not** changing any iterable (and no itterable, either, as that's not a thing).

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you iterate over a `list` you actually call `list.__iter__()`, which returns a `listiterator` object bound to the `list`, and then actually iterate over this `listiterator`. Technically, this:

```
itt = [1, 2, 3]
for i in itt:
    print i
```

is actually kind of syntactic sugar for:

```
itt = [1, 2, 3]
iterator = iter(itt)
while True:
    try:
        i  = it.next()
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print i
```

So at this point - within the loop -, rebinding `itt` doesn't impact the `listiterator` (which keeps it's own reference to the list), but *mutating* `itt` will obviously impact it (since both references point to the same list).

IOW it's the same old difference between rebinding and mutating... You'd get the same behaviour without the `for` loop:

```
# creates a `list` and binds it to name "a"
a = [1, 2, 3] 
# get the object bound to name "a" and binds it to name "b" too.
# at this point "a" and "b" both refer to the same `list` instance
b = a 
print id(a), id(b)
print a is b
# so if we mutate "a" - actually "mutate the object bound to name 'a'" - 
# we can see the effect using any name refering to this object:
a.append(42)
print b

# now we rebind "a" - make it refer to another object
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
# at this point, "b" still refer to the first list, and
# "a" refers to the new ["a", "b", "c"] list
print id(a), id(b)
print a is b
# and of course if we now mutate "a", it won't reflect on "b"
a.pop()
print a
print b
```

Comment: Can you expand a little more? Are there other objects, where this is the same case?

Comment: @Dschoni depends on what you mean by "same case"... wrt/ the "mutating vs rebinding" part, that's just how Python works - "variables" are not "memory buckets", just names referencing objects. If you want to know more about the iterator protocol, it's fully documented in Python's FineManual,   but you can get an intro and more references here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols

Answer (score 5):

In the first loop you are changing the `it` object (inner state of the object), however, in the second loop you are reassigning the `it` to another object, leaving initial object unchanged.

Let's take a look at the generated bytecode:

```
In [2]: def f1():
   ...:     it = range(6)
   ...:     for i in it:
   ...:         it.remove(i + 1)
   ...:         print i
   ...:         

In [3]: def f2():
   ...:     it = range(6)
   ...:     for i in it:
   ...:         it = it[:-2]
   ...:         print it
   ...:         

In [4]: import dis

In [5]: dis.dis(f1)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (6)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (it)

  3          12 SETUP_LOOP              36 (to 51)
             15 LOAD_FAST                0 (it)
             18 GET_ITER            
        >>   19 FOR_ITER                28 (to 50)
             22 STORE_FAST               1 (i)

  4          25 LOAD_FAST                0 (it)
             28 LOAD_ATTR                1 (remove)
             31 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             34 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             37 BINARY_ADD          
             38 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             41 POP_TOP             

  5          42 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             45 PRINT_ITEM          
             46 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             47 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           19
        >>   50 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   51 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             54 RETURN_VALUE        

In [6]: dis.dis(f2)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (6)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (it)

  3          12 SETUP_LOOP              29 (to 44)
             15 LOAD_FAST                0 (it)
             18 GET_ITER            
        >>   19 FOR_ITER                21 (to 43)
             22 STORE_FAST               1 (i)

  4          25 LOAD_FAST                0 (it)
             28 LOAD_CONST               2 (-2)
             31 SLICE+2             
             32 STORE_FAST               0 (it)

  5          35 LOAD_FAST                0 (it)
             38 PRINT_ITEM          
             39 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             40 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           19
        >>   43 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   44 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
```

As you can see, `for` statement works with an iterable of `it` (`GET_ITER` instruction, `iter(it)`). Therefore, reassigning the `it` variable will not affect the loop iteration.

Comment: You have my upvote for the use of `dis` because I never saw that before and that looks amazingly awesome. I'm going to inspect my clearification case myself.

Comment: That's why I love Python - it provides a lot of amazing things out of box

Answer (score 4):

First, it is essential to understand what happens under the hood when you run a simple for-loop, like:

```
for i in it: pass
```

At the beginning of the loop, an *iterator* is created. That iterator is the result of an implicit call to `iter(it)`.  This is the *only* time the variable named `it` is referenced in the above loop. The rest of the references happen when `next` is called on that iterator, but it uses the object the iterator keeps a reference to, not the object the name `it` is bound to.

What does this mean for your second example?

Note that in your second example, you do not change the list inplace, but create a new list and bind the variable `it` to it.

It means the iterator keeps referencing the original list, which is unchanged.

In your first example, you change the original list in place, therefor calls to `next(iterator)` reflect those changes.